# Python How an iterator variable increases or decreases

Tags: python-3.x

Coming from another language just wondering how do I increase or decrease an iterator variable.

```
i = 3
for a in range(1,i):
    if a == 1:
        i = 5
    print(i)
```

It does not iterate four times as I am expecting.

Comment: You can't with a `for` loop. `for` loops iterate an existing sequence from its start to end. You may be able to create your own custom `range` iterator object that allows its position in the range/end position to be modified while you're looping, but no built-in iterators support that afaik. You need a `while` loop and manual `i += 1` handling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your idea. This does work therefore posted own answer for future readers.

```
   i = 1
    j = 3
    while i < j:
      print(i)
      if i == 1:
          j = 5
      i += 1
```

Comment: u need to keep in mind that in Python indentation is serious and ur code will show an error unlike other languages like C++ and Java.